# What are the default resouces allocated to an ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

With a dataflow we can specify the server size, but not with pipelines.
Pipelines still move and manipulate data, so must have resources allocated to them.

Is there a way to see or adjust the resources that are are allocated to a pipeline, or does azure just assign what's needed?

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines do not actually move and manipulate data, rather they orchestrate other services. Those services (activities) are responsible for their own performance concerns. That means a lot depends on how those services are configured at the source, physical location, latency, etc.

Data Flow activity has performance configuration because it is a wrapper around a managed Spark cluster. Copy activity is the exception as Data Factory manages that environment, but it has its own [performance guidance and options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance). Otherwise, Pipelines don't really have any adjustable resources.